# My dropdown selected value is not being posted to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to C# mvc.
I have a simple form containing a dropdown list whose values are being populated from a ViewBag

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetSliderValues", "Slider",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("dvalue",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.names) 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

After submitting the form I am trying to get the selected value in the Controller as

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetSliderValues()
{
    ProviderName p = new ProviderName();
    p.Name = Request.Form["dvalue"];
    return View(p);   
}
```

But I am not receiving any value. p.Name is always being set to null.

Comment: The code you have shown will work fine and `Request.Form["dvalue"]` will return the value of the selected option

Comment: But its not...The dropdownlist field is not even being posted

Comment: Of course it is based on the code you have shown (albeit your code is dreadful practice). What makes you think its not?

Comment: you do not reuse the selected values in your view...

Answer (score 2):

Notice that you're not trying to POST data but GET it. That's why you need to use FormMethod.Get instead of FormMehod.Post.

then, just try to create a new SelectList instead of an IEnumerable of SelectListItem.

In your View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetSliderValues", "Slider",FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("dvalue",new SelectList(ViewBag.names))
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

And then in your controller just Add an string parameter:

```
public ActionResult GetSliderValues(string dvalue)
{
    ProviderName p = new ProviderName();
    p.Name = dvalue;
    return View(p);   
}
```

Finally remove The `[HttpPost]` decorator and it should Work

Comment: this should not be the concern :-)